# how can I add windows store template to visual studio 2013?

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2013, windows, external-tools

I have visual studio 2013 and 64x win 7 pc.

I want to create a windows phone app with a single button and textbox.

When I click file>new>project I cant see windows store in templates.

I couldnt find how to search online from tools>external tools.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you installed [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?
The sdk contains the components needed to develop windows store apps.

If you are going to develop Windows phone 8.0 instead of 8.1, this [XDA forum thread](http://forums.windowscentral.com/software-development-hacking/257343-tut-install-full-wp8-sdk-windows-7-a.html) should help you. I haven't personally tried that because I am looking to develop Windows 8.1 in Win 7 x64.

You can also try to install the [SDK 8.0 and 8.1 lite version by Arnold Vink](http://dhost.info/vink/avink/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=4&sid=ccbd2d48ec5475ae2495402fe47fe82f). I tried the sdk 8.1 lite version with no luck but perhaps it will work for you.

You can check out [my SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347714/developing-window-store-apps-in-visual-studio-2013-on-window-7-64-bit-without-em/30349285#30349285) on what I have done so far. Hope this helps.

Comment: After Installing the WP 8 SDK Lite version on my Windows 7 PC - 64 bit , I am not able to debug Web Apps in VS2013 ..
I tried repairing VS2013 - didn't work.
Tried Uninstalling VS2013 and Reinstalling - didn't work.
Tried Uninstalling VS2013, .NetFramework4.51 and 4.5 and then Re-Install VS203- didn't work.

Any idea what changes are made the SDK Lite version that doesn't allow Debugging Web Projects?
By Debugging I mean , when I try to Run the Web App , CS2013 starts IIS express the Web site tries to connect on the port but then fails and debugging stops without giving any error.

Comment: @Vipresh: Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve that as it had been very long since I am using it. Perhaps you can get more clues in looking at the bat file that are used to install the SDK. From there you should be able to know what changes had been made and hopefully able to revert those changes.

Comment: @wiz-lee, Unfortunately I had to format my machine and reinstall VS2013. As You have suggested I didn't check the bat files but if I remember clearly all they had was instructions for launching installers one after another. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Vipresh: That is unfortunate, sorry about that man for causing the trouble.